# How to extract the minimum value in all columns in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, extract, multiple-columns, minimum

I am working on mass spectrometry proteomics expression data. For statistical analysis of the data, I have to find the top three minimum value of each column in the dataframe like below,

```
structure(list(Type = c("knn_vsn", "knn_loess", "knn_rlr", "lls_vsn", 
"lls_loess", "lls_rlr", "svd_vsn", "svd_loess", "svd_rlr"), Group1 = c(0.00318368971435714, 
0.00317086486813191, 0.00317086486813191, 0.00312821095645019, 
0.00311632537571597, 0.00313568333628438, 0.00394831935666465, 
0.00393605637633005, 0.00395599132474446), Group2 = c(0.0056588221783197, 
0.00560933517836751, 0.00560933517836751, 0.00550114679857588, 
0.00548316209864631, 0.00550230673346083, 0.00737865310351839, 
0.0073411154394253, 0.00735748595511963), Group3 = c(0.00418838138878096, 
0.00417201215938804, 0.00417201215938804, 0.00398819978362592, 
0.00397093259462351, 0.00398827962107259, 0.00424157479553304, 
0.00422638750183658, 0.00424175886713471), Group4 = c(0.0039811913527127, 
0.00394649435912413, 0.00394649435912413, 0.00397059873107098, 
0.00393840233766712, 0.00396385071387178, 0.0041077267588457, 
0.00407577176849463, 0.00410191492380459)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), groups = structure(list(
    Type = c("knn_loess", "knn_rlr", "knn_vsn", "lls_loess", 
    "lls_rlr", "lls_vsn", "svd_loess", "svd_rlr", "svd_vsn"), 
    .rows = structure(list(2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 7L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L), .drop = TRUE))
```

And I need the output like below,\

```
structure(list(`Type ` = c("lls_loess", "lls_rlr", "lls_vsn"), 
    Group1 = c(0.00311632537571597, 0.00313568333628438, 0.00312821095645019
    ), ` Type` = c("lls_loess", "lls_rlr", "lls_vsn"), Group2 = c(0.00548316209864631, 
    0.00550230673346083, 0.00550114679857588), `  Type` = c("lls_loess", 
    "lls_rlr", "lls_vsn"), Group3 = c(0.00397093259462351, 0.00398827962107259, 
    0.00398819978362592), `Type  ` = c("lls_loess", "lls_rlr", 
    "lls_vsn"), Group4 = c(0.00393840233766712, 0.00396385071387178, 
    0.00397059873107098)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Please suggest some useful R code for this issue.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to write your *for you*, though the community is very willing to help you solve problems you encounter whilst *writing it for yourself*. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?  Also, the meaning of "top three minimum" is not clear.  Do you mean "the three smallest values in each column"?

Comment: Don't knn_loess & knn_rlr have the 2nd and 3rd lowest values for Group4? Is the specified output actually what you want?

Comment: @Limey, Yes I am telling about "top three smallest values in each column" only. And also, I am the beginner in R program. This question may be asked before by someone that I don't know. So if there is some error in my question or in my way of questioning, please forgive me. And I will learn R basics.

Comment: @JonSpring, Yes knn_loess & knn_rlr are the 2nd and 3rd minimum values in Group4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Type) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  slice_min(value, n = 3) %>%      # You might stop here, already tidy
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = c(Type, value),
              names_vary = "slowest")
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 × 9
    row Type_Group1 value_Group1 Type_Group2 value_Group2 Type_Group3 value_Group3 Type_Group4 value_Group4
  <int> <chr>              <dbl> <chr>              <dbl> <chr>              <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>
1     1 lls_loess        0.00312 lls_loess        0.00548 lls_loess        0.00397 lls_loess        0.00394
2     2 lls_vsn          0.00313 lls_vsn          0.00550 lls_vsn          0.00399 knn_loess        0.00395
3     3 lls_rlr          0.00314 lls_rlr          0.00550 lls_rlr          0.00399 knn_rlr          0.00395
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://statisticsglobe.com/select-top-n-highest-values-by-group-in-r)

data <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:3], each = 5),data
value = 1:3)
data

Comment: The link is great, but you should explain your answer here as well because links can disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `purrr::imap_dfc`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

imap_dfc(2:ncol(df), ~ df %>% ungroup %>% .[c(1,.x)] %>% 
 slice_min(df[[.x]], n = 3) %>% set_names(c(paste0("Type",.y), names(df)[.x])))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 8
#>   Type1      Group1 Type2      Group2 Type3      Group3 Type4      Group4
#>   <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 lls_loess 0.00312 lls_loess 0.00548 lls_loess 0.00397 lls_loess 0.00394
#> 2 lls_vsn   0.00313 lls_vsn   0.00550 lls_vsn   0.00399 knn_loess 0.00395
#> 3 lls_rlr   0.00314 lls_rlr   0.00550 lls_rlr   0.00399 knn_rlr   0.00395
```

Note: Your original data is grouped: that is why I use `ungroup` in my solution.